# Using WinUI 2.3 in an Uno shared project

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml, uno-platform, winui

I've been excited about Uno but at the end of the day, I'm a diehard Windows 10 M supporter and would like to publish an app for the platform before it's completely buried and impossible to target.

To get fun new controls in Windows 10 15063, I need WinUI 2.3, but I'd like to use Uno.UI alongside it.

If I use the guide for WinUI installation, my Windows build works just fine. The issue [TwoPaneView with Uno Platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60931965/twopaneview-with-uno-platform) seemed promising but the only answer falsely asserts that not using a namespace with TwoPaneView will build on Windows 10 -- maybe with 1903 minimum but not with 15063 minimum in release mode.

How do I properly juggle the namespaces? I'm okay with splitting out a few per-project files if I have to but I would rather not.

Answer (score 0):

Ahem... In point of fact, I didn't "falsely assert" anything!

WinUI and Uno.UI will **build** just find in a UWP head project targetting the Windows 10 Creators Update (Build 15063) however you can't use the ".NET Native tool chain" with such an old SDK.

You can check this by changing the min targetting version of my "TwoPainView" project ([from here](https://github.com/ibebbs/TwoPainView)) and compiling (in debug or release without "Compile with .NET Native tool chain") which will result in no errors but a couple of (entirely sensible) warnings along the lines of:

> Type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.TwoPaneView' is defined under contract 'Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract' version '8.0.0.0', but the contract version for the targeted min version is '4.0.0.0'!

And this is correct. It is unlikely you will be able to use the TwoPaneView on such an old SDK.

Comment: There's quite a lot wrong here. For one, WinUI 2.3 explicitly supports 15063, and the .NET Native toolchain also does. I'm completely able to get TwoPaneView working with WinUI 2.3 on 15063, compiling with .NET Native (as evidenced by broken reflection support), deploying on Windows 10 Mobile 15063.

Comment: Yea your sample isn't even touching WinUI. WinUI is a misleading name, since the type of the control should be Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls.TwoPaneView if it's coming from WinUI.